# Returning the column name(s) where a search term is found, using PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, search

Example: I have a table with 5 fields, named id, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4
And I am searching for 'foo' across all fields.

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE field_1 LIKE ('%foo%') OR field_2 LIKE ('%foo%') OR ...
```

I'd like to return the IDs, as well as which fields the term was found in.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Note: I am looking for a solution that could dynamically accommodate adding new DB fields, without having to manually update the SQL.

Comment: What'is supposed to happen if the string is found in more than one field?

Comment: @TheWolf -- it would show each field occurence, ideally.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to map these matches in returned columns:

```
SELECT ID, 
       field_1 LIKE '%foo%' AS field_1_match,
       field_2 LIKE '%foo%' AS field_2_match
...
```

... so you can just check each corresponding `column_match` value to know, well, was it matched or not.

It's easy to extend this into returning a string with columns (separated by `,`, for example) with `CONCAT_WS`:

```
SELECT ID, 
       CONCAT_WS(',',
         IF(field_1 LIKE '%foo%', 'field_1', NULL),
         IF(field_2 LIKE '%foo%', 'field_2', NULL)
         ... 
       )
```

... but, honestly speaking, I doubt it'll be easier to process data formatted this way.

Comment: I see how this could work for a small number of fixed fields, but was hoping to find something dynamic, such that it could accommodate new fields being added, without manually updating SQL. I will add that to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Use unions:

```
SELECT id, 'field_1' as 'fieldName' FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE '%foo%' UNION
SELECT id, 'field_2' as 'fieldName' FROM table WHERE field2 LIKE '%foo%' UNION
...
```

This will return the id and column name wherever it is found. If it happens multiple times on the same row, multiple results will be returned for that row.

Updated:

It is possible to dynamically search all of the tables using a stored procedure and a cursor.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE search_all_fields(IN search VARCHAR(100), IN tableName VARCHAR(100), IN idColumnName VARCHAR(100)) 
BEGIN

    DECLARE sqlQuery VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE columnName VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_NAME`= tableName; # cursor will iterate over the column names
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp ( id VARCHAR(100), FieldName VARCHAR(100) ); # procedure returns multiple result sets, so we'll dump them in a temp table and get them at the end
    OPEN cur;

    read_loop: LOOP # iterates through column names
        FETCH cur INTO columnName;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        # execute search
        SET @sqlQuery = CONCAT("INSERT INTO temp SELECT ", idColumnName, ", '", columnName, "' as 'FieldName' FROM ", tableName, " WHERE ", columnName, " LIKE '%", search, "%'");
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlQuery;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;
    # grab the results
    SELECT * FROM temp;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This will take me a bit to digest. Thanks.